# Rendering a form with some unique and some multiple fields of same type

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine

I have a form which has several unique fields for that form say, **School**, **class**, 
**Location** etc and several fields that needs to be repeated say, , **Student id**, **Student name**, **Student roll no**.
I want to repeat the last three fields 10 times.  
Secondly, how do I store it in database (MySQL using doctrine). I mean rows should be created depending on the number of last three fields and the first three fields should remain same.
How do I achieve this in a Symfony2? 
Any help will be highly appreciated.
The form structure is something like this:
School     Class    Location

Sno   Student id      Student Name   Student Roll No
1.
2.
3.
4.
5.
And so on......
**Edit: Fixed at 10 rows**
**Update**
Entity Class:

    `class StudentForm
    {`

```
private $id;

private $school;

private $class;

private $location;

private $id;

private $name;

private $rollNo;
```

getter/setter methods follow

Comment: It's a bit complicated when you do it the first time, but the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html) is pretty good on this.

Comment: This is infact the first time I'm doing this and trust me I have no idea how and where to start.

Comment: I did go through that documentation page but couldn't understand.

Comment: Well, basically you will have a form for each entity you try to edit/add. And then one form which will include the others. This is called "embedding" of a form or entity in symfony2. With a bit of JavaScript the user then will be able to create new sub-entities. All this works hand-in-hand with your entities and relations between them. My advice would be to first create all your entities and relationships and add some values into the database just to see that everything works out. After that start creating the embedded forms to edit such an entry. Again, the documentation is pretty good.

Comment: If you say so, I'll try again. Don't need Javascript as the number of rows are fixed at 10.

Comment: OK. Make sure you understand where to add those 10 embedded forms then.

Comment: If you have worked on this can you tell me where do I exactly create 10 instances of these form fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a good long process of trial and error, I finally managed to do it.
The doctrine documentation helped creating a collection (though it didn't give enough information on saving the objects) for the repeating rows and so did the inputs of @Dirk Olbertz here. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well. Up to now I always used the JavaScript provided in the example. You could try to call this function 10 times, or see how the markup is created. But then again this will probably not work with the code in the controller from the example.

You can always create the whole markup yourself and then just see who that data is received in your controller. But then again, there wasn't too much information in your initial description. It seemed you currently don't have the code for your entities.

Comment: I have the entity class created and even the form type class but I don't think that's needed. Anyways, I pasted some parts of the entity class.

Comment: OK. The thing here seems to be the "rollNo". You could just have 10 fields in your entity. Often such a thing indicates a poor database design. What happens when those need to be 12 or if in addition to the number an active/inactive state needs to be added? It probably might be better to have a new entity "enrollment" (just guessing) with the "number" as a field and then adding a relationship between your "student" and your "enrollment". There are so many ways to achieve your goal that it's difficult to just give you one answer.

Comment: I guess you deviated from the problem I'm actually facing. I guess you didn't read my question carefully. Nonetheless, I appreciate your help and thank you for your time.